# Linking react and express

Tags: reactjs, express

I am stuck trying to link express with react.

here is my webpack file

```js
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./js/app.js",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
        }
      },
      { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192' }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/src/",
    filename: "client.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};
```

This is the js/app.js file

```js
var express = require('express')
var db = require('./db')

var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/all', function(req, res) {
  var collection = db.get().collection('comments')

  collection.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
    res.render('comments', {comments: docs})
  })
})

app.get('/recent', function(req, res) {
  var collection = db.get().collection('comments')

  collection.find().sort({'date': -1}).limit(100).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    res.render('comments', {comments: docs})
  })
})

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
  res.send('../index.html');
})
```

The app.js links to index.html for a '/' path. The index.html looks something like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <title>React</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.6/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="txtstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!-- Custom Fonts -->
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="client.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am running my script by `webpack && node ./src/js/app.js`. I can not however get the index.html to run. On going to localhost:3000 I get a `'../index.html'` text.

I have no idea as in how to link these two things (express and react) together. With what modifications on my code can I get them to work together?

Also I get this long error and warning messages from the above command

```
WARNING in ../~/require_optional/package.json
Module parse failed: /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/require_optional/package.json Unexpected token (2:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:9)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:581:61)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseExpressionStatement (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:966:10)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:730:24)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseBlock (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:981:25)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:709:33)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at NormalModule.<anonymous> (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at NormalModule.onModuleBuild (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
    at Storage.provide (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:52:20)
    at CachedInputFileSystem.readFile (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:140:24)
    at NormalModule.onLoadPitchDone (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:255:7)
    at NormalModule.loadPitch (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:182:27)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:241:4)
    at NormalModule.build (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:84:14)
    at Compilation.buildModule (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:126:9)
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:309:10
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:58:13
    at NormalModuleFactory.applyPluginsAsyncWaterfall (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:75:69)
    at onDoneResolving (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:38:11)
    at onDoneResolving (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:121:6)
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:116:7
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:726:13
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
 @ ../~/require_optional ^\.\/.*$

WARNING in ../~/require_optional/LICENSE
Module parse failed: /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/require_optional/LICENSE Unexpected token (1:40)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:40)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:581:61)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseExpressionStatement (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:966:10)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:730:24)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at NormalModule.<anonymous> (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at NormalModule.onModuleBuild (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
    at Storage.finished (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:415:3)
 @ ../~/require_optional ^\.\/.*$

WARNING in ../~/require_optional/README.md
Module parse failed: /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/require_optional/README.md Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp$7.getTokenFromCode (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2756:10)
    at Parser.pp$7.readToken (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2477:17)
    at Parser.pp$7.nextToken (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2468:15)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:515:10)
    at Object.parse (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at NormalModule.<anonymous> (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at NormalModule.onModuleBuild (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
    at Storage.finished (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:415:3)
 @ ../~/require_optional ^\.\/.*$

ERROR in ../~/express/lib/request.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'net' in /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/express/lib
 @ ../~/express/lib/request.js 18:11-25

ERROR in ../~/mongodb/lib/gridfs/grid_store.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/mongodb/lib/gridfs
 @ ../~/mongodb/lib/gridfs/grid_store.js 42:7-20

ERROR in ../~/mongodb/package.json
Module parse failed: /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/mongodb/package.json Unexpected token (2:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:9)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:581:61)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseExpressionStatement (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:966:10)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:730:24)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseBlock (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:981:25)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:709:33)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at NormalModule.<anonymous> (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at NormalModule.onModuleBuild (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
    at Storage.provide (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:52:20)
    at CachedInputFileSystem.readFile (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:140:24)
    at NormalModule.onLoadPitchDone (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:255:7)
    at NormalModule.loadPitch (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:182:27)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:241:4)
    at NormalModule.build (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:84:14)
    at Compilation.buildModule (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:126:9)
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:309:10
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:58:13
    at NormalModuleFactory.applyPluginsAsyncWaterfall (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:75:69)
    at onDoneResolving (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:38:11)
    at onDoneResolving (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:121:6)
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:116:7
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:726:13
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
 @ ../~/mongodb/lib/server.js 22:20-59

ERROR in ../~/express/lib/view.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/express/lib
 @ ../~/express/lib/view.js 18:9-22

ERROR in ../~/send/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/send
 @ ../~/send/index.js 24:9-22

ERROR in ../~/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'net' in /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection
 @ ../~/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js 5:10-24

ERROR in ../~/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'tls' in /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection
 @ ../~/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js 6:10-24

ERROR in ../~/statuses/codes.json
Module parse failed: /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/statuses/codes.json Unexpected token (2:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:7)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:581:61)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseExpressionStatement (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:966:10)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:730:24)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseBlock (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:981:25)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:709:33)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at NormalModule.<anonymous> (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at NormalModule.onModuleBuild (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
    at Storage.finished (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:415:3)
 @ ../~/statuses/index.js 15:12-35

ERROR in ../~/etag/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/etag
 @ ../~/etag/index.js 22:12-25

ERROR in ../~/mongodb-core/package.json
Module parse failed: /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/mongodb-core/package.json Unexpected token (2:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:9)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:581:61)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseExpressionStatement (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:966:10)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:730:24)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseBlock (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:981:25)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:709:33)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at NormalModule.<anonymous> (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at NormalModule.onModuleBuild (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
    at Storage.provide (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:52:20)
    at CachedInputFileSystem.readFile (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:140:24)
    at NormalModule.onLoadPitchDone (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:255:7)
    at NormalModule.loadPitch (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:182:27)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:241:4)
    at NormalModule.build (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:84:14)
    at Compilation.buildModule (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:126:9)
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:309:10
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:58:13
    at NormalModuleFactory.applyPluginsAsyncWaterfall (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:75:69)
    at onDoneResolving (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:38:11)
    at onDoneResolving (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:121:6)
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:116:7
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:726:13
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
 @ ../~/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/shared.js 17:20-62

ERROR in ../~/destroy/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/destroy
 @ ../~/destroy/index.js 14:17-30

ERROR in ../~/require_optional/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/require_optional
 @ ../~/require_optional/index.js 2:7-20

ERROR in ../~/mime/mime.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/mime
 @ ../~/mime/mime.js 2:9-22

ERROR in ../~/mime/types.json
Module parse failed: /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/mime/types.json Unexpected token (1:27)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:27)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:581:61)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseExpressionStatement (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:966:10)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:730:24)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseBlock (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:981:25)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:709:33)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at NormalModule.<anonymous> (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at NormalModule.onModuleBuild (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
    at Storage.finished (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:415:3)
 @ ../~/mime/mime.js 87:12-35

ERROR in ../~/resolve-from/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'module' in /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/resolve-from
 @ ../~/resolve-from/index.js 3:13-30

ERROR in ../~/mime-db/db.json
Module parse failed: /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/mime-db/db.json Unexpected token (2:40)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:40)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:581:61)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseExpressionStatement (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:966:10)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:730:24)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseBlock (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:981:25)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:709:33)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at NormalModule.<anonymous> (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at NormalModule.onModuleBuild (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
    at Storage.finished (/Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
    at /Users/lpuser/Projects/SlantedLines/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:415:3)
 @ ../~/mime-db/index.js 11:17-37
Express server is up on port 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u tell web pack which file to resolve? I think you are missing that part, also try to use path. Join(__dirname, 'otherpath' ) rather the __dirname.  Try that and see what webpack say.

Thats my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require("webpack");
//var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var AssetsPlugin = require('assets-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: [
            'react-hot-loader/patch',
            'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&timeout=20000',
            path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index')
        ]
    },
    devtool: 'inline',
    // this is a default value; just be aware of it context: path.resolve(__dirname,
    // 'app'),
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, "www"),
        publicPath: "/assets/"
    },
    plugins: [ // added this thing!
        new(webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin || webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin)(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new AssetsPlugin()
        //new HtmlWebpackPlugin({title: "React express", template: "public/template.ejs"})
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json", ",", '.map']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: [
                    'react-hot-loader/webpack', 'babel-loader'
                ],
                include: path.join(__dirname)
            }, {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: [
                    'react-hot-loader/webpack', 'babel-loader'
                ],
                include: path.join(__dirname)
            }, {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader']
            }, {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            }, {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 10000
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Thats my .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015","stage-0", "stage-0", "react"],
  "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
}
```

Comment: A new problem has occurred now. I linked my entry point to the client.js file that contains the routing and all, but now the index.html file that is pointing towards the client.min.js can not find this file. It is looking in the location, localhost:3000/client.min.js . This thing already exists in the directory, why is it looking in the url ?

Comment: Your client.min.js should be at src/clinet.min,js as your output.path refer to /src folder.

Comment: Also i think it should be res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname),"index.html"). Use path.join("__dirname,"other folder")) to reslove your path in every path instance.

Comment: If you look at my index.html, It has `<script src="client.min.js"></script>` thing. This file loads all fine (the index.html) , but on checking the networks in my browser, I found that it is requesting for this file from localhost:3000 (the express port) and hence is getting a 404 not found errror. But the file is right there in the src folder, along with the index.html.

Comment: try like this <script src="./client.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

> By using transform-class-properties my application code is transpile
>   into es5 correctly.
>   
>   **This is my .babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015","stage-0", "react"],
  "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel","transform-decorators-legacy", "transform-class-properties]
}
```

> if you don't want to use decorator then you could use simple stage-1
>   like this which i generally used in my project. and In Here i have
>   also separated production and development. My development is using
>   react-hmre for hot reloading.

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-1"
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": [
        "react-hmre"
      ]
    },
    "production": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-react-constant-elements",
        "transform-react-remove-prop-types",
        "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```